# Evaluating limit of $L^1$ norm

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n(x)= \dfrac{\sin 2 \pi x \,\sin 2\pi n x}{x^2}$. Show that $\|f_n\|_1 \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For large $n$, approximate the integral $\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n} |f_n|$ for $k = 1,2,\ldots,\sqrt{n}$, by approximating $x^2$ and $\sin 2\pi x$ as constants and simply computing $\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n} |\sin 2 \pi n x|$.  You will get each answer proportional to $1/k$ for each $k$, so as $n \to \infty$ the integral $\int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{n}} |f_n|$ diverges at least as fast as $1/1 + 1/2 + \ldots + 1/\sqrt{n}$.